# tf2_ros.Buffer.transform() in Python (Tutorial is lacking?)

Tags: ros, python, ros-melodic, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

#### Situation

I have the following rough TF(2) setup (simpified):

```
odom -> base_link -> tool_link
```

where

- `odom` is generated by the diff drive controller from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller).
- `base_link` is the "root" of my mobile base (ie it moves around)
- `tool_link` is the tf frame of a tool into which I want to transform coordinates

Now I would like to transform sensor measurements that I receive as `PoseStamped` messages in the `odom` frame into the `tool_link` frame.

#### What I tried

- I followed the Python tutorials until [here (writing a tf2 listener in Python)](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20listener%20%28Python%29). The solution seems to be at the bottom of the page. However, the [MessageFilter approach](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Using%20stamped%20datatypes%20with%20tf2%3A%3AMessageFilter) mentioned there only contains an example for C++.
- Searching rosanswers brought up [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/49069/is-there-a-tfmessagefilter-in-the-tf-python-api/) - where the guy just implemented his own filter in python. The answer is also pretty old so Id hope that there is something more recent?

#### The Current Code

My code follows the abovementioned tutorial, ie (stripped down version):

```
import tf2_ros
tfBuffer = tf2_ros.Buffer()
listener = tf2_ros.TransformListener(tfBuffer)
try:
    trans = tfBuffer.lookup_transform(turtle_name, 'turtle1', rospy.Time())
    # MARKER (Transform point here? See below)
except (tf2_ros.LookupException, tf2_ros.ConnectivityException, tf2_ros.ExtrapolationException):
    continue
```

This works so far. However, it leaves me with a transform message that I would still need to apply to the input message The problem here is basically [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/146111/tf-python-api-transform-points/) - but that answer is for tf1. For tf2, as far as I understand the following should be used to transform a PointStamped (and therefore be inserted at MARKER in the above code):

```
tfBuffer.transform(pose_stamped_to_be_converted, "tool_link", timeout=rospy.Duration(10.0))
```

But that line fails with

```
Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 166.496000000 but the earliest data is at time 170.614000000, when looking up transform from frame [odom] to frame [m2_blade_horizon]
```

The delta between requested and earliest time is always in the range above ~2-8s. As you can see I have picked a very large timeout (to hopefully rule out [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/323902/tf2-extrapolationexception-error-python/)), even though the tf publishers for the revelant frames at all running at 10+Hz.

#### Questions

- How do I get the above transform to work (actually using tf2 - what is the point of using tf2 if I still have to do the transform myself?)
- Is there any tf2 python documentation that I missed?
- Was an "official" python message filter developed in the meantime?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369778/tf2_ros.buffer.transform()-in-python-(tutorial-is-lacking?)/) by [blubbi321](https://answers.ros.org/users/23248/blubbi321/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2021-01-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the fix here (pretty sure I tried it before without it working though): https://answers.ros.org/question/367262/tf2-i-can-broadcast-transfroms-but-i-cannot-listen-to-them-i-keep-getting-error-lookup-would-require-extrapolation/

The trick is to just take the last available transform from the buffer, ie for my example above:

```
pose_stamped_to_be_converted = PoseStamped()
pose_stamped_to_be_converted.header.stamp = rospy.Time(0)
[..]
transformed_posestamped = tfBuffer.transform(pose_stamped_to_be_converted, "tool_link", timeout=rospy.Duration(10.0))
```

---

Originally posted by [blubbi321](https://answers.ros.org/users/23248/blubbi321/) with karma: 95 on 2021-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0